Force ifort to ignore the error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument
I am trying to compile this Fortran code using ifort (version 2022.1.0). I am getting an error:
error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.

I already found that this error is serious - the code might be faulty, and it should be fixed, though nobody is maintaining this software anymore.
Anyway, I found that it is possible to compile such codes with Intel Visual Fortran by setting:
Properties -> Fortran -> Diagnostics -> Check Routine Interfaces -> [No]

Unfortunately, I cannot use this solution because I am using only the command-line version of ifort. Is it possible to set something in the ifort.cfg file to achieve the same result?
EDIT.
Probably, the code needs fixing and cannot be compiled as is. As requested in the comments below, I post the code fragment which produces an error:
subroutine aovec_aosph_nw2ac(ntot,natom,aoind,aostr,geoind,trmat,fileout)
   use mod_fun
   use mod_print
   implicit none
   integer ntot,natom,fileout
   integer aoind(ntot,5),geoind(natom,3)
   double precision trmat(ntot,ntot)
   character(4) aostr(ntot,2)
   integer aotmp(5)
   integer i,j,k,b1,b2,c1,c2,k1,k2,l1,l2,m1,m2

!  aoind(i,j,k,l,m) i:nw-order/j:atom/k:ang/l:ang(lz)/m:ang(lz,ind)
!  geoind(a,b,c)    a:atom/b:atom-group/c:group-ind
!  aces-ind         b->k->l->m->c
   do i = 1,ntot-1
   do j = i+1,ntot
      ! atom group
      b1=geoind(aoind(i,2),2)
      b2=geoind(aoind(j,2),2)
      if (b2.lt.b1) then
         call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
      elseif (b2.eq.b1) then
         ! angular momentum
         k1=aoind(i,3)
         k2=aoind(j,3)
         if (k2.lt.k1) then
            call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
         elseif (k2.eq.k1) then
            ! angular momentum (z-axis)
            l1=aoind(i,4)
            l2=aoind(j,4)
            if (l2.lt.l1) then
               call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
            elseif (l2.eq.l1) then
               ! angular momentum (z-axis,index)
               m1=aoind(i,5)
               m2=aoind(j,5)
               if (m2.lt.m1) then
                  call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
               elseif (m2.eq.m1) then
                  ! atom group index
                  c1=aoind(i,2)
                  c2=aoind(j,2)
                  if (c2.lt.c1) then
                     call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
                  endif
               endif
            endif
         endif
      endif
   enddo
   enddo

   write(fileout,'(/,a)') '* aolab (nwchem rotated)'
   do i = 1,ntot
      write(fileout,'(5i5,2a4)') (aoind(i,j),j=1,5), &
           (aostr(aoind(i,1),k),k=1,2)
   enddo

   trmat(1:ntot,1:ntot) = 0.0d0
   do i = 1,ntot
      trmat(aoind(i,1),i) = 1.0d0  
   enddo

   write(fileout,'(/,a)') '* trmat (nwchem rotated)'
   call print_rmat(trmat,ntot*ntot,ntot,ntot,fileout,2)
end subroutine aovec_aosph_nw2ac

When I try to compile it using the command:
ifort file.f90

I get the following:
file.f90(21): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [NTOT]
         call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
------------------------^
file.f90(21): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [AOIND]
         call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-----------------------------^
file.f90(21): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [I]
         call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-----------------------------------^
file.f90(21): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [J]
         call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-------------------------------------^
file.f90(27): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [NTOT]
            call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
---------------------------^
file.f90(27): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [AOIND]
            call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
--------------------------------^
file.f90(27): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [I]
            call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
--------------------------------------^
file.f90(27): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [J]
            call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
----------------------------------------^
file.f90(33): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [NTOT]
               call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
------------------------------^
file.f90(33): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [AOIND]
               call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-----------------------------------^
file.f90(33): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [I]
               call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-----------------------------------------^
file.f90(33): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [J]
               call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-------------------------------------------^
file.f90(39): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [NTOT]
                  call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
---------------------------------^
file.f90(39): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [AOIND]
                  call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
--------------------------------------^
file.f90(39): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [I]
                  call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
--------------------------------------------^
file.f90(39): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [J]
                  call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
----------------------------------------------^
file.f90(45): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [NTOT]
                     call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
------------------------------------^
file.f90(45): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [AOIND]
                     call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-----------------------------------------^
file.f90(45): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [I]
                     call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-----------------------------------------------^
file.f90(45): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [J]
                     call rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,i,j)
-------------------------------------------------^
file.f90(66): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.
   call print_rmat(trmat,ntot*ntot,ntot,ntot,fileout,2)
-----------------------------^
file.f90(66): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [NTOT]
   call print_rmat(trmat,ntot*ntot,ntot,ntot,fileout,2)
-----------------------------------^
file.f90(66): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [NTOT]
   call print_rmat(trmat,ntot*ntot,ntot,ntot,fileout,2)
----------------------------------------^
file.f90(66): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [FILEOUT]
   call print_rmat(trmat,ntot*ntot,ntot,ntot,fileout,2)
---------------------------------------------^
compilation aborted for file.f90 (code 1)

This is the subroutine for rot_aoind:
subroutine rot_aoind(ntot,aoind,ind1,ind2)                                                                                                       
   implicit none
   integer ntot,aoind(ntot,5),ind1,ind2
   integer k,aotmp(5)
   do k = 1, 5  
      aotmp(k)      = aoind(ind1,k) 
      aoind(ind1,k) = aoind(ind2,k)
      aoind(ind2,k) = aotmp(k)
   enddo
end subroutine rot_aoind


It may well be possible to set something in the global configuration file, but don't you really just want to use a compiler flag on the command line?

You are totally right. I can use the compiler flag. Which flag should I use in this case?

I'm assuming you're using Windows with which I'm entirely unfamiliar: my guess at what that option is called won't be useful. The compiler's documentation is hopefully similarly helpful to that on other systems that a search for "interfaces" should quickly yield your answer.

What needs to be done may depend on exactly what the code is, and indeed what you consider to be "very old". It would help if you edit the question to include both the calling point of the procedure and it's declaration, including all dummy argument declarations. Is the procedure in a module?

I am using Debian Linux.
@IanBush Yes, the procedure is in a module. I don't know if I can post parts of this code here due to copyright. However, I can link you to the exact file that has the problem with compilation: aovec.f90

If the procedure is in a module you will almost certainly need to fix the code (and this is not what I would call "very old" by any stretch). Beyond that without at least the name of the routine causing the problem and the code for the actual call we can't say much more - just that link is not nearly enough.

According to the license file the code is covered by GPL, so there will be no problem posting any relevant code.

I edited the question and added the code. I also deleted the words "very old" :)

We need the interface for rot_aoind. The problem is that the the provided actual arguments do not agree with the dummy arguments as declared in that routine. Without both bits on information we can't answer the question.

I edited the answer with the requested piece of code.

Well that all looks good to me. Please tell us the exact command that was used to compile function.f90, the file that contains rot_aoind? Also why are you not using hte makefile to compile this?

Actually, I do use make. To be exact, when I am within the folder, I use the make ARCH=X86_64 OPSYS=linux CMPLR=intel command.

Well from what you have said I can see nothing wrong - the arguments match in type, kind and rank. What I do find strange is you github repository has the .mod files in it, so a complete guess is that the mod_fun.mod file is out of date and produced by either a different compiler, or the same compiler but with a different set of compiler flags one of which changes the data types. So I suggest a make clean and a complete remake from scratch. But I am guessing - there is a huge amount in the background here which I don't know (e.g. the exact flags from the makefile)

I have also downloaded the four files you need to test this form the repository (print.f90 function.f90 get_aces2.f90 aovec.f90) and it compiles for me successfully using both ifx and ifort (but not with gfortran which finds some broken code in function.f90). So there is something in your environment you haven't told us about. I can get the error you report if, for instance, I compile function.f90 with the -i8 flag but don't include it for aovec.f90. Which is just yet another example of why -i8 and equivalent is just plain evil and should never be used.

If you're using the Windows version for comparison, you can find the exact command line that was used by going to Properties / Fortran / Command Line.  That may be helpful in identifying how a particular toggle in the UI representation of the options ends up reflected in the command line.

I found the solution on the Intel forum, exactly in this answer. Well, I would call it more a "workaround" than a "solution."
For some reason, ifort is "confused when the type comes from the module currently being compiled". So what I did was:

Move the troublesome file outside the directory (in this case, aovec.f90)
Compile other files just using the make command.
Move the file back and compile it again.

Finally, it compiled successfully.
Thank you, @IanBush and @francescalus, for your help and suggestions!

According to the link, it was fixed in a ~2015 version of ifort.  I'm surprised that it's apparently occurring again with a 2022 version.

I also checked on another machine in which I have the 2023 version - exactly the same behavior.
